# CoreData - Get posts and ONLY their unremoved comments

Tags: core-data, nspredicate, relationship, core-foundation

I have two collections:

```
- Post
- Comment

Post.comments = [comment1, comment2, ...]
```

`comment.removed` is a boolean.

I'd like to fetch all Posts but exclude `comments` which are removed. Is there a way to do it without iterating over the OneToMany relationship ?

Here is what I tried:

```
ANY comments.removed == FALSE  // Posts that have at least one removed comment
ALL comments.removed == FALSE  // Posts that only have unremoved comments
(SUBQUERY(comments, $x, $x.removed == FALSE).@count > 0) // Same as the first one
```

Comment: Do you use scalar values or is your `removed` property of type `NSNumber`? Try to use `NO` instead of `FALSE` or `[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO];`

Comment: The `removed` property is a boolean. Of course, the getter/setter use NSNumber to interface with CoreData. Actually, `removed == FALSE` works well on other queries (for instance when looking for unremoved posts). I just need a way to include subentities while filtering them.

Comment: But, does "what you have tried" work?

Comment: They produce expected results, but it's not what I want. I just explained what I tried to get filtered subentities. They didn't filter `Comment` but `Post` :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your problem correctly, you would like to get all "Post" objects, but `post.comments` should not be the entire set of comments as defined in the Core Data store, but only the set of comments that are not removed.

This is not possible (as far as I know) with a fetch request, because the result of a fetch request is a list of objects in the managed object context. A fetch request can not return *new* objects that are *different* from their original in the managed object context.

Answer (score 0):

It may be worthwhile to explain your motivation for not wanting to retrieve "removed" comments from CD, when you could programmatically exclude them quite easily when it comes time to use them. Is the volume large enough to be a performance burden?

In any case, it should be possible to create an `NSArrayController`, bound to each comment collection in turn, but set up a fetch predicate to exclude "removed" comments.

See the [apple docs on this subject](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/Articles/pUsing.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001794-SW8) for more - good luck!

Comment: After retrieving `Post.comments[removed=FALSE]` will directly be used in an UITableViewController. If a fetch request can't filter subentities, I have to iterate over `Post.comments` and exclude removed comments before sending them to the table view. Nothing about performances, I just think it's ugly.

Comment: It sounds like you are trying to display all non-removed comments, ordered by post, in a table view. -- Is that right, or do you just want the non-removed comments for a particular post? Also, it is not clear from the OP that this is iOS-specific.